# Django shell(plus) timeout on remote database connection

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm migrating a legacy db into a bunch of models I have running locally. I connected to the legacy db and ran inspectdb to recreate the models. Now I'm writing functions to pair the numerous fields to their equivalents in new models. I've been using shell_plus, and the first minute or so of queries go great, but my connections keep timing out
with the following:

```
RemoteArticle.objects.using("remote_mysql").all()    
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Is there a command I can run to either a) reconnect to the db before running a query (so I don't have to reopen shell_plus), or ideally b) make it so that all of my queries automatically reconnect each time I run them?

I've seen timeout issues on other platforms, but I wasn't sure if Django had a built-in way of handling such things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [page in the MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html) docs on this. Since you're apparently trying to migrate a big database, this part may apply to you:

> Sometimes the “during query” form happens when millions of rows are
>   being sent as part of one or more queries. If you know that this is
>   happening, you should try increasing net_read_timeout from its default
>   of 30 seconds to 60 seconds or longer, sufficient for the data
>   transfer to complete.

The timeout makes sense, because the `all()` is just *one* query to retrieve all rows. So, reconnecting before each query is not the solution. If changing the `net_read_timeout` is not an option, you might want to think about paging.

Comment: Confirmed: the issue was indeed that my queries were simply too large/demanding too much data, and the MySQL connection was timing out after a while. This server isn't frontend-client-facing so I was able to increase the timeout without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Lost connection to MySQL server during query` happens because you exhaust the MySQL resource like timeout, session, and memory.

If the problem is because of the timeout, try increase the timeout `--net_read_timeout=100.` On the DB server.